# Convert from matrix to list matrix

Tags: r

Sorry for the noob question but I can't seem to get this to work!

X=cbind(rep(1,m), h2(x), h3(x)) #obs

So I have a 17*3 matrix X I have to create a matrix(list(),17,3) version of this matrix. I did manually below so you can see the desired result, but there must be an easier way to do this?

```
Z=matrix(list(X[1,1],X[2,1],X[3,1],X[4,1],X[5,1],X[6,1],X[7,1],X[8,1],X[9,1],X[10,1],X[11,1],X[12,1],X[13,1],X[14,1],X[15,1],X[16,1],X[17,1],X[1,2],X[2,2],X[3,2],X[4,2],X[5,2],X[6,2],X[7,2],X[8,2],X[9,2],X[10,2],X[11,2],X[12,2],X[13,2],X[14,2],X[15,2],X[16,2],X[17,2],X[1,3],X[2,3],X[3,3],X[4,3],X[5,3],X[6,3],X[7,3],X[8,3],X[9,3],X[10,3],X[11,3],X[12,3],X[13,3],X[14,3],X[15,3],X[16,3],X[17,3]),17,3)
```

I tried this (amongst others)

```
Z2=list(X[1:17,1],X[1:17,2],X[1:17,3])
Z3=matrix(Z2[1:3],17,3)
```

But it doesn't give the correct results! It just repeats the three column vectors over and over.

Can someone please explain how to do this correctly.

Comment: As in `mode(X)<-"list"`?

Comment: So as in the example where I create Z you take each element of X which is 17,3 matrix and create a list of these elements. This list is then used to create a 17,3 matrix of the list elements. The only way I can do it is to manually input the elements from the matrix into the list. There must be a simpler way?

Comment: Your question is not clear. It sound like you might just want to store each numeric element as a list element instead. In which case, see my first comment....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you want `Z <- matrix(as.list(X), ncol = 3)`. However, I don't see how this structure could be useful.

Comment: I need to put it into this form so that it can be used by a third party function I'm really not sure why they use this form either